# Getting data-id from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using ASP.net/C# with jQuery and i'm trying to get the value in data-id. I have the following code:

Markup:

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddLocations" Text="Update" CssClass="btn btn-info pull-right addLocation" />
```

Code behind (basically adds the data-id attribute)

```
SPID = "3"
btnAddLocations.Attributes.Add("data-id", SPID);
```

jQuery:

```
$(".addLocation").click(function () {
        var id = ($(".addLocation").data("spid"));
        alert(id);
        var url = "popups/AddLocations.aspx?spid=" + id;
        window.open(url, "Add Locations", "width=600,height=550");
        return false;
    });
```

However, ID always comes back as undefined

Comment: Isn't it: `var id = $(".addLocation").data("id");` ???

Comment: @A.Wolff It is, you should add it as an answer...

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon that's ok, Satpal get it ;)

Comment: Gah, ever have one of those long days and look at it for ages knowing it's so simple! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use

```
var id = $(this).data("id");
```

OR

```
var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to get value set as 'data-spid' in HTML DOM

```
SPID = "3"
btnAddLocations.Attributes.Add("data-spid", SPID);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is more easy way to pass id from button to javascript

```
   function DoEdit(e)
   {
       alert(e.toString());
   };
```

<
input id="btnAddLocations" onclick="DoEdit('<%# Eval("SPID") %>')" value="GetID"/>